# How can I convert 302 to 301 redirect?

Tags: magento2, nginx, redirection

`https://newsite.com to https://www.newsite.com` results in a 302 redirect. Not sure from where this temporary redirect is coming. Site nginx configuration has only 301 redirects. Here is the configuration.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54603417/nginx-301-redirect-from-oldsite-to-newsite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the 302 redirect comes from Magento, because you call without the configured host in your url.

Try something like this in your nginx:

```
if ($host != 'www.newsite.com'){
    return 301 https://www.newsite.com$request_uri
}
```

Comment: Having 302, would that have any negative impact on seo?

Comment: I'm not a SEO expert but they say 301 it's better. But anyway it's better (for example for performance reasons) to make the redirect by the webserver than by application

Answer (score 1):

For each redirect, you can add the following line to your nginx configuration, inside of the location / block (first):

```
rewrite /old/url.html /new/url.html
```

**I hope this will help**